# Notepad ++ How to find lines with X spaces (not less and not more)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find lines in notepad ++ with only X number of spaces - for example 3 spaces (not less and not more). Text in notepad include different languages like arabic ( الجديده) russian (моя собака) etc. I cant find any regex solution to bookmark all lines i need... Please help:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do:

```
^(?:[^ ]* ){3}[^ ]*$
```

This will match lines that have exactly 3 spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the space in front of {3}. Keep in mind that this only search for 3 spaces like you've asked, no other requirements are met.

```
 {3}
```

Comment: This will match any number of spaces, more than 3.